# Can't use chmod to alter permissions on emulated phone

Tags: adb, android-emulator, file-permissions

So, I'm trying to make an app in android studio and I need to reference a particular file in the app, `cascade.xml.` I've pushed it onto the emulated phone no problem using adb (it's in the storage/sdcard folder). However, the app still can't access it and I think that's because the file permissions are `-rwxrwx---` (which means no global access). These permissions are verified in ADM and using `ls -l <filename>`

I try to change the permissions of that `cascade.xml` file by going back into the shell (`adb shell`) using `chmod 777 /storage/sdcard/cascade.xml`, but it fails quietly and doesn't do anything. Tried doing other chmods, and nothing happens to it at all. If I do `su` and then `chmod 777 /storage/sdcard/cascade.xml`, same thing. Trying to do other `chmod`s like `chmod 700` and the like also do nothing (quiet fail).

Now, if I try to make a directory in the folder, I can do that using `mkdir` - `mkdir /storage/sdcard/cascades` works fine, and the file permissions of the folder are `drwrwx---`. However, if I try to use `mkdir chmod` to create the folder and end up with the same permissions - like `mkdir chmod 770 /storage/sdcards/cascades2` - the shell says `mkdir failed for chmod, Read-only file system`. I can also make text files doing something like `echo 'Hello World.' > /storage/sdcard/foo.txt` (which creates it with permissions of `-rwxrwx---`), but if try to `chmod` it afterwards, nothing happens.  If I try to do `echo 'Hello World.' > storage/sdcard/foo2.txt chmod 777, it's the same permission but the file size is 24 instead of 14.

I've done every iteration of `mount` and `remount` I can think of, and I still can't get chmod to work properly. I've tried running `su` in front of everything, and nothing. I've tried starting with `adb root`, and it says I'm already in root. I can also push stuff the emulator using ADM and `adb push`. Unfortunately, all of my environment is on a Windows 7 device, so I can't just make a file with `-rwxrwxrwx` permissions and just transfer it across (unless there's a permission setting in Windows that will make it transfer over as a 777 permission that I don't know about).

Edit: Forgot to mention, the emulated phone is running API 19, target Google APIs (x86 System), running KitKat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out - seems like you just can't change permissions for files on `sdcard`. Moved it to `data/local` and `chmod` worked like a charm.