# chmod and chown silently fail in shell for TwinApps media directory

Tags: adb, permissions, shell

I think I have a similar issue to [Can't use chmod to alter permissions on emulated phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135432/cant-use-chmod-to-alter-permissions-on-emulated-phone) but the emulation is happening on the android device itself via the TwinApps feature, which allows you to use multiple copies of an app that doesn't support multiple accounts (in this case, WhatsApp).

I would like to copy a photo to overwrite the profile photo of one of the accounts into the directory. Unfortunately trying to open the folder on the device itself or via adb, the app's folders in media are Permission Denied. No matter what I try I cannot get into the folder.

Here is interesting output of ls -la (I made a tmp folder which I was able to rm later)

```
total 6
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a228    media_rw 3452 2022-04-15 14:53 test
drwx--S--- 3 u2357_a228 media_rw 3452 2022-04-03 13:08 com.whatsapp
```

This 'u2357_a228' user is likely the emulated app user, and I have no idea how to become it to mess with the folder inside. Like I said, chmod and chown just fail silently.

Any tips on what I can do are appreciated.

Comment: android 11 scoped storage - use built-in file manager

Comment: @alecxs same issue even with built-in file manager. Shows up as an empty folder and that I have no permissions.

Comment: probably intended because you only have permissions for profile 0. can you login to another profile maybe? I am afraid there is no way to access